# How do you disable Google Chrome SafeBrowsing while using Puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer, safe-browsing

I've been using [Puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) to automate user journeys through various web portals and one of the things I've run into is the constant popups caused by using bad credentials. In this case, the browser told me that the password I'd just logged in with had been seen in a data breach. Now, this isn't a concern because they are testing credentials. However, I can see how this can easily mess up the script for other people where they can't just change their credentials.

Here is the dialog that I've been trying to get rid of:

[image: Data breach dialog]

The main problem is that the dialog completely disrupts the Puppeteer script and causes it to fail. I don't know how to auto-dismiss these popups, but I would assume these would still mess up the script while it's trying to fill in fields and click buttons. Worse still, when running the script in headless mode, it will not be readily apparent to the user that the script failed at the login page because of their bad password.

I know you can prevent this dialog from showing by going into Chrome Settings and disabling SafeBrowsing (chrome://settings/security), however, this is not something that then works when using Puppeteer as it is configured differently. I searched through this [huge list of command line arguments](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) for Google Chrome and I couldn't find anything specific to specifically disabling password breach dialogs or disabling SafeBrowsing entirely.

I saw there was a Windows-specific trick where you could write a Group Policy to the Windows Registry, but I need the solution to be cross-platform (i.e. also work on MacOS and Linux). Also, it's important that the solution isn't reliant upon using my user data directory as I need this script to work on other computers and even remote servers when I'm running Puppeteer in headless mode.

Example code which is enough to run into the issue. Note the main problem is not the code, but the use of a common password found in a data breach.

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

async function launchPuppeteer() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        defaultViewport: null,
        executablePath: '/path/to/chrome/executable',
        headless: false,
        args: [ /* Chrome command line args go here */ ]
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    // use page here . . .
}
```

Is there any command line argument for Chrome, or functionality within Puppeteer, to disable SafeBrowsing?

Comment: A simple code snippet would make it easier to help here. Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen I've added a small snippet to the question. However. it's less of a coding question and more of a Puppeteer and Google Chrome question. I hope it helps though.

Comment: So that dialog pops up without a `page.goto()` for you? For me, no alerts show up so I can't reproduce this. Why does your browser have passwords in it? An automated browser is generally totally fresh on every run, without any saved browser state such as credentials. If you're using `userDataDir`, can you do your automation without it so you have clean state? Or change the password to something safe?

Comment: @ggorlen The script types in the login form, then clicks on the submit button. It then waits for a specific element on the next page. The submit button fires off a POST request to the server, and Chrome then checks that submitted password - it's not pulling it from a list of saved passwords (there aren't any). It's that specific password that was typed into the field which is then complained about. The fresh browser has SafeBrowsing turned on by default, which is what is causing the error. Therefore I need to know how to disable that feature.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I feel like something is missing. I mean, when I run Puppeteer's Chromium, I can type in `name` and `1234` into password inputs to log in to sites and I've never seen a complaint from Chromium in 4+ years of automating stuff. Have you tried not using `executablePath: '/path/to/chrome/executable'` and allowing Puppeteer to use its built-in clean browser? I know you want to switch this feature off, and that'd be great if someone happens to know how, but I feel like it shouldn't be a problem in the first place, or should be easy to work around.

Comment: @ggorlen I would love to be able to figure out what's missing because the first time I've seen this was today. I'm pretty sure this SafeBrowsing popup isn't even new. Perhaps the data leak that the password was on is recent or something. It's weird that you haven't seen this despite using simple passwords. I'm not sure what info I can really add to the question.

Comment: I don't think there's anything to add, other than to try using Chromium, or one of the other workarounds I've suggested. Or just wait for someone to maybe answer this in the future (unlikely to happen soon--I'm the most active Puppeteer answerer).

Answer (score -1):

I do not know the exact reason, but when I used this args, this error was resolved after that

[
'--autoplay-policy=user-gesture-required',
'--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows',
'--disable-breakpad',
'--disable-client-side-phishing-detection',
'--disable-component-update',
'--disable-default-apps',
'--disable-dev-shm-usage',
'--disable-domain-reliability',
'--disable-extensions',
'--disable-features=AudioServiceOutOfProcess',
'--disable-hang-monitor',
'--disable-notifications',
'--disable-offer-store-unmasked-wallet-cards',
'--disable-popup-blocking',
'--disable-print-preview',
'--disable-prompt-on-repost',
'--disable-renderer-backgrounding',
'--disable-setuid-sandbox',
'--disable-speech-api',
'--disable-sync',
'--hide-scrollbars',
'--ignore-gpu-blacklist',
'--metrics-recording-only',
'--mute-audio',
'--no-default-browser-check',
'--no-first-run',
'--no-pings',
'--no-sandbox',
'--no-zygote',
'--password-store=basic',
'--use-gl=swiftshader',
'--use-mock-keychain',
]